# Simple 4x4 Cryptic Crossword

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

Most words are in English (are foreign words allowed?), although some are more obscure than others.

[image: a standard 4 by 4 crossword grid, with Down clues numbered 1, 2, 3, 4 from left to right across the top and Across clues numbered 1, 5, 6, 7 from top to bottom along the leftmost column]

Clue transcription:

| **ACROSS** | **DOWN** |
| --- | --- |
| 1. Chicken providers have urges | 1. Great spices mixed up after trimming |
| 5. Father in agony | 2. A nag up a Sanskrit flock |
| 6. Iron out of place in traditional Japanese case | 3. A grotesque grin; a smirk |
| 7. Slang for halving drinking containers | 4. Mucus is not held in |

Comment: Could you provide a transcription of the grid and clues? Images are non-searchable and non-accessible.

Comment: @bobble I tried to resize the image with SO Markdown, but there's not an easy way to do that, so I just added the clues to pad it out - I added the clue transcription, but what do you mean by transcribing the grid? Something like ASCII art?

Comment: I meant adding an image description, should've been more clear. I've done it for you. It's not strictly necessary - the title should communicate the grid well enough - but being more explicit can't hurt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The filled grid:**

> [image]

---

**Answers and clue explanations:**

1. Chicken providers have urges

> EGGS, double definition.

5. Father in agony

> PA+IN.

6. Iron out of place in traditional Japanese case

> INRO: anagram of IRON.

7. Slang for halving drinking containers

> CANT: definition "slang", from CANT(-eens).

1. Great spices mixed up after trimming

> EPIC; anagram of (-s)PICE(-s).

2. A nag up a Sanskrit flock

> GANA (reversal); a Sanskrit word meaning "flock".

3. A grotesque grin; a smirk

> GIRN (anagram of grin; British word meaning "smirk", roughly)

4. Mucus is not held in

> SNOT (hidden word in "is not"; in my experience, hidden words should be fully contained, not using the first or last letters. I don't think it's quite appropriate to say that SNOT is "held in" ISNOT, because it's not 'fully' inside it.)

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks for the feedback; still trying to learn the ins and outs of cryptic clues :)